# SMS not delivering to numbers in some country

Tags: android, sms

I have developed an android application.For confirming users mobile number ,i am sending a confirmation code to the user entered number from the android application.The application is working fine in my country(India),but in some countries the message is not getting delivered.what should be the reason?.I am sending the confirmation code to the user entered number with out adding the country code.

PS:mostly the sender and the receiver will be same

Comment: I have, over the last 10 years or so used 4 different providers of SMS, and every single one has had problems to some country or another. Basically the only way to *guarantee* rapid delivery in a given country, is to find a provider in that country, and use them (And even then rapid delivery is not always guaranteed)

Comment: i am sending the confirmation code to same same number.and listening the broadcast for the confirmation SMS,if the SMS is not delivered in 30 second i am providing the option to manually add the confirmation code.but the SMS is not delivering at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Would not including the country code be the problem?

Also you may want to look at the libphonenumber code library, a powerful way to validate and format phone number. https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: i cant figure out the problem,normally for sending SMS within the same country(user is sending SMS to same number or his another number) not required the country code.